# NK model.TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

Tags: python

I am trying to get Kauffman's NK model. It is giving error on line 31

```
f = open(options.in_filenames)'
```

> Traceback (most recent call last): File "F:\WoRk\simulations\nkprocess.py", line 33, in <module> f = open(options.in_filenames,"F:/WoRk/social network") TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

```
import csv
from numpy import *
import Gnuplot
import time
from optparse import OptionParser
from pylab import *
# set up and read command line options


parser = OptionParser()
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", dest="in_filenames",
                  help="read data from FILE - enclose comma-separated   file list in quotes e.g. \"FILE1, FILE2\"", metavar="FILE")


(options, args) = parser.parse_args()



# set up constants

# column titles
columnvar_titles = (["A", "N", "K"])
series_titles = (["Average Fitness", "Maximum Fitness","Minimum Fitness",
       "Average Wait Before Move","Maximum Wait Before Move",
       "Minimum Wait Before Move","Average Number of Fitter Neighbours",
       "Maximum Number of Fitter Neighbours",
       "Minimum Number of Fitter Neighbours"])


f = open(options.in_filenames)
reader = csv.reader(f)
floats = []
options_dict={}
```

Comment: your got invalid file path or filename.*work with fullpath, not with argument style.

Comment: How are you calling your script?

Comment: So, what can I do about my script?